# OutputText for dynamic Value

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

```
<td >
Fees: <apex:outputtext value="{! If(abInsurance !=null,'Rs. {!abInsurance.charges__c}',If(xyInsurance!=null,'Rs. {!xyInsurance.charges__c}','None')) }"/> 
</td>
```

Only one of the Insurance can have value at a time.

I cannot check the VF page, but is the above code correct for retrieving the dynamic value for field 'charges_c'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place expressions inside expressions. You would want to remove the extra bits.

```
Fees: <apex:outputtext value="{!If(abInsurance !=null,'Rs. ' & abInsurance.charges__c, If(xyInsurance!=null,'Rs. ' & xyInsurance.charges__c,'None')) }"/>
```

Comment: I updated my code according to your suggestion but I got below error:
Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number

For time sake I am using below code, but currently digging more into '&' operator:
Fees: Rs. <apex:outputtext value="{!If(abInsurance !=null, abInsurance.charges__c, If(xyInsurance!=null, xyInsurance.charges__c, '0')) }"/>

Comment: @PritishKumbhare I should have figured that was a number field. You could use TEXT() to convert it to a String, but I actually like your suggestion even better.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox for TEXT() and previous suggestion. Both of them were helpful.